Scroll Collection centeredHorizontally Iphone SE
I have a collection, which has a function that centers a certain section. The problem is that on the iPhone 14 Pro the section is centered, but on the iPhone SE it does not center, with the index completely on the right. I need it to work like an iPhone with a larger screen.
caroulselView.collectionCarousel.reloadData()
caroulselView.collectionCarousel.layoutIfNeeded()
caroulselView.selectItemAndScroll(setIndex)

func selectItemAndScroll(_ setIndex: Int = 0 ) {
    let startIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: setIndex)
    collectionCarousel.selectItem(at: startIndexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally)
}

Iphone SE
Iphone 14
Currently my collection has 11 indexes and I always want to start with my eighth position. Is there any way to make this work on iPhone SE too?

There is no reason for that code to behave differently on an iPhone 14 Pro vs an iPhone SE ... You have 11 sections and each section has 1 item? Quick test, no problem... At what point in the controller lifecycle are you executing this code?

along with loading the view. 11 sections with 1 item.

Without seeing all of your code, it's very possible that you are calling .selectItemAndScroll(setIndex) too early in the controller lifecycle. Here is some sample code that works ... (unless the collection view is too wide to center section 8, such as if you launch the app in landscape orientation): https://pastebin.com/7HncGHe9 -- give that a try. See if you can tell where it differs from your code. If you can't get your code working, review [mre] and post enough code that we can run it and see what's going on.

I managed to solve the problem. All you had to do was change the size of the right and left sides. Before, only values ​​were set on the left.
